# Scraping thousands of web pages

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I am working on a project which requires cron to scrape thousands of web pages in one run.
I have found lots of links over Google but could not find any suitable solutions. I have used file_get_contents, cURL etc. but script always fails in between execution. I have hosted my websites on shared server.

And I also want to grab data of web pages every day. It would be a great help if someone can draw me to the right solution for my problem.

Comment: Post the code that you have tried, and we can help you to debug it.

Comment: So what is your question? And what have you done already? If you want us to suggest a solution for you then this question might get closed as opinion based.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your language of choice. You could use

1. selenium
2. file_get_content or equivalent function in your lanugaue

Answer (score 0):

You should split your requests on cron.
It doesn't mater, using wget or curl. Your script will fail because of time or memory limit.
For example you can split your cron jobs :

```
wget http://yoursite.com/yourCrawler.php?group=0
wget http://yoursite.com/yourCrawler.php?group=1
wget http://yoursite.com/yourCrawler.php?group=2
```

etc. And also you should make changes on your crawler to support split.